# Q object django returns empty QuerySet when AND together

Tags: python, django

In the django shell, when I filter individual Q object, it returns correct QuerySet. But when the same Q objects are AND together, it returns an empty QuerySet.

```
File.objects.filter(Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='1112'))
<QuerySet [<File: abc.txt>]>

File.objects.filter(Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='5368'))
<QuerySet [<File: abc.txt>]>
```

But when I combine the Q objects with AND, it returns empty set:

```
File.objects.filter(Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='1112') & Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='5368'))
<QuerySet[]>
```

Comment: Are you sure the two QuerySets from the individual queries contain the same `File` object?

Comment: That is logical since you query a *related* object. But Django will, if you query related objects with several queries, filter the *same* related object.

Comment: class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class RelatedJira(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: this is the effect of having multiple constraints of an existentially quantified condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the combined query, it will only return files that have a single `relatedjira` where the content contains both `'1112'` and `'5368'`.

If you put the `Q` objects in separate filters, then it will return files that have a `relatedjira` where the content contains `'1112'` and another `relatedjira` where the content contains `'5368'`

```
File.objects.filter(Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='1112')).filter(Q(relatedjira__content__icontains='5368'))
<QuerySet [<File: abc.txt>]>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is logical. If you query for *related* objects, Django's filter mechanism is existential: so if one `relatedjira` has this content, that is enough.

If you however perform multiple filters with the relation, these all have effect on the *same* related object. It is possible that for a given `File`, there are two `RelatedJira`s, one with `1112`, and one with `5368`, but if you query with the two, then this does not yield an element, since the two `RelatedJira`s are different ones.

For example:

```
+---------------+      +-------+      +---------------+
| RelatedJura   |  ->  | File1 |  <-  | RelatedJira   |
+---------------+      +-------+      +---------------+
| content: 5368 |                     | content: 1112 |
+---------------+                     +---------------+
```

Your first query reads:

> Give me the `File`s for which there is a related jira where the content contains `1112`.

And this succeeds.

The second query reads:

> Give me the `File`s for which there is a related jira where the content contains `5368`.

And this succeeds.

but the last query is:

> Give me the `File`s for which there is a related jira where the content contains `1112` and `5368`.

and this fails, since there is no such `RelatedJira` that contains *both* substrings.

Comment: In both your Alasdair's answers, I notice the lack of links to documentation and at least a quick search through the django docs did't reveal anything either. Is this behaviour unique for `Q` objects. Or would it be the same for `filter(relj__content='1112').filter(relj__content='5368')` vs `filter(relj__content='1112', relj__content='5368')`? Also, if the two filter kwargs go along *multiple* relations, will the existential scope go all the way to the last common one?